# Functional way to loop over ordered set in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm in R that runs over an ordered set of values and determines whether there are values 'in the future' ( further down the set ) that have a lower value than the given value.

For example:

```
+-------+--------------------------------+
| Value | RestOfSeriesContainsLowerValue |
+-------+--------------------------------+
| 5     | true                           |
| 4     | true                           |
| 2     | true                           |
| 1     | false                          |
| 3     | true                           |
| 4     | true                           |
| 4     | true                           |
| 3     | true                           |
| 3     | true                           |
| 2     | false                          |
| 2     | false                          |
| 2     | false                          |
| 7     | false                          |
| 8     | false                          |
| 9     | false                          |
| ...   | ...                            |
+-------+--------------------------------+
```

The local minima are values 1 and 2. Therefore RestOfSeriesContainsLowerValue for the first items in this set valuates to true - since there's a value (1) further down the set that has a lower value.

After the 1 value - the 3 and 4 values valuate to true, since the new local minimum ( value 2 ) is coming up later down the set.

We're currently using a for loop that runs over the - in pseudo code:

```
for (i in set) {
   if(value(i) <=  min(set[,i:end])) 
     RestOfSeriesContainsLowerValue(i) = true
   else
    RestOfSeriesContainsLowerValue(i) = false
}
```

However this is not efficient enough. I'm looking for a set based / functional way to write this in R but cannot get my head around it. Can I use `lapply` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo code in functional R code using lapply

```
f <-function(value) unlist(lapply(seq_along(value), function(i)if(value[i] <=  min(value[i:length(value)]))FALSE else TRUE))
```

Vectorized code for achieving the same is

```
f1 <- function(value)value > rev(cummin(rev(value)))
```

Depending on the sample size, the vectorized code can be arbitrarily faster. For `n=100` it is about 10 times faster, 100 times faster for `1000`, around 1000 times faster for `10000`

```
value <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f(value), f1(value), unit="relative")
#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f(value) 172.3758 174.2449 124.1607 107.5502 104.8017 96.85548   100
#f1(value)   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000   100
```

Comment: thanks - awesome! I'm checking this out right now. Man - how can I trigger my brain to think differently and come up with a solution like the 2nd? Are you just brilliant or did you learn it from somewhere? Or do you have trick for this?

Comment: @spike Glad it helped. The trick is to get yourself well acquainted with handful of vocabularies, for instance, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Vocabulary.html .