# Find min value among rows including and below given row by group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe where I need to group by `Mat` and find the minimum `value` at each row from among rows including and below given row. Code shows test data and my code for doing this. Field `min_value` is the desired output. Wondering if there is a `tidyverse` way to do this -

```
df <- structure(list(Mat = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), value = c(11L, 22L, 0L, 22L, 33L, 43L, 108L, 
152L, 0L, 486L, 706L, 830L)), .Names = c("Mat", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

group_by(df, Mat) %>%
  mutate(
    min_value = sapply(row_number(), function(a) min(value[a:length(value)]))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Mat   value min_value
   <chr> <int>     <int>
 1 A        11         0
 2 A        22         0
 3 A         0         0
 4 A        22        22
 5 A        33        33
 6 A        43        43
 7 B       108         0
 8 B       152         0
 9 B         0         0
10 B       486       486
11 B       706       706
12 B       830       830
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do...

```
df %>% group_by(Mat) %>% mutate(v = rev(cummin(rev(value))))

# or maybe more 'verse-like
df %>% group_by(Mat) %>% mutate(v = value %>% rev %>% cummin %>% rev)

# or ...
below_min = . %>% rev %>% cummin %>% rev
df %>% group_by(Mat) %>% mutate(v = below_min(value))
```

Or with data.table (which modifies `df` itself)...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[order(.N:1), v := cummin(value), by=Mat]
```

---

There's a similar Q&A over here, if anyone is interested:

- [Functional way to loop over ordered set in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29522390/1191259)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at `cummin` but didn't figure out the `rev()` logic.